# Unable to access knockout observable array item

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I fetch data from web api and push the data into observable array. I would like to make the observable array item to be observable. However, it seems that i could not access the object if i make it observable.

```js
function KnockoutViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.ProfileList = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.GetProfile = function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      success: function() {
        $.each(data.ProfileList, function (index, value) {
           self.ProfileList.push(value);
           alert(self.ProfileList()[index].Name) // success
        }
      }
    });
  }
      
  self.GetProfile();
}
           
function KnockoutViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.ProfileList = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.GetProfile = function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      success: function() {
        $.each(data.ProfileList, function (index, value) {
           self.ProfileList.push(ko.observable(value));
           alert(self.ProfileList()[index].Name) // fail. Object does not support property or method 'Name'
        }
      }
    });
  }
      
  self.GetProfile();
}
```

Comment: `alert(self.ProfileList()[index]().Name)` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are directly pushing `object` (by making it observable) into observableArray does it sound right ? Nah (you may want to make `Name` as observable i believe) . Tough you can get the output by doing something like this `self.ProfileList()[index]().Name` check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27297/)**

**Preferred way :**

**viewModel:**

```
 function convert(data) {
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.Name)
    this.place = ko.observable(data.place)
    this.age = ko.observable(data.age)
}

function KnockoutViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ProfileList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.GetProfile = function () {
        var data = [{
            'Name': 'Super',
                'place': 'Ind',
                'age': 25
        }, {
            'Name': 'Cool',
                'place': 'Aus',
                'age': 15
        }]

        //Manual way with function defined 
        //self.ProfileList(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (value) {
        //  return new convert(value)
        //}))

        //Using Mapping Plugin
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{},self.ProfileList)
    }
    self.GetProfile();
}

ko.applyBindings(new KnockoutViewModel());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27301/)**

Comment: besides name, i have address, contact etc how could i combine inside?

Comment: @stacknist edited my answer it can be done in 2 ways . 1)mapping plugin 2) manually mapping using `.arrayMap` . To check the functionality comment/uncomment b/w them & check it .

Comment: thanks for the clarification. currently i am using the ko.mapping.fromJS way. Suppose that i would like to manually update the place of index 1 how could it be done? I have try this but it is not working.  self.ProfileList()[1]().Place = '123';

Comment: @stacknist you have to do assigning for a observable using `()` convention not `=` i.e `self.ProfileList()[1]().Place( '123');` . cheers

Comment: @stacknist again you are wrongly using things `()[1]()` check here working sample http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27304/

Comment: it shows error message Uncaught TypeError: self.ProfileList(...)[1] is not a function

Comment: @stacknist weird man ! are you using the same code as above then you should try `self.ProfileList()[1].Place( '123')` no extra `()`

Comment: self.ProfileList()[1].Place( '123'). this works thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the mapping module:

```
self.ProfileList.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(value));
```

This will automatically wrap value's properties in knockout observables.